# augemtation error, tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, tensorflow, data-augmentation

Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: `<class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType'>`

I am trying to implement  deep learning model and I have run the code more than 10 times , some times in 41, 72,88,100 epoch I got this error, is there anybody to help me

```
def Tuning_Model():        
    
    for k in range(FOLDS):           
        timestamp = datetime.fromtimestamp(time()).strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
        output_directory =  model_path + "\\" + timestamp 
        if not os.path.exists(output_directory):
            os.makedirs(output_directory)        
        # Training image augmentation
        train_data_generator =tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1. / 255,
            fill_mode="constant",
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=(0.5, 1),
            horizontal_flip=True,
            rotation_range=360,
            channel_shift_range=25,
            brightness_range=(0.75, 1.25))

        # Validation image augmentation
        val_data_generator =tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
            rescale=1. / 255,
            fill_mode="constant",
            shear_range=0.2,
            zoom_range=(0.5, 1),
            horizontal_flip=True,
            rotation_range=360,
            channel_shift_range=25,
            brightness_range=(0.75, 1.25))

        test_data_generator =tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

        train_data_generator = train_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
                                    train_data_path,
                                    target_size = RAW_IMG_SIZE,
                                    batch_size  = BATCH_SIZE,
                                    class_mode  ='categorical'
                                    )
                                  
        val_data_generator = val_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
                                    val_data_path,
                                    target_size = RAW_IMG_SIZE,
                                    batch_size  = BATCH_SIZE,
                                    class_mode  = 'categorical')
               
        test_data = test_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
                                    test_data_path,
                                    target_size = IMG_SIZE,
                                    batch_size  = BATCH_SIZE,
                                    class_mode  = 'categorical',
                                    shuffle     = False)

        
        train_data_generator = crop_generator(train_data_generator, IMG_SIZE)
        val_data_generator   = crop_generator(val_data_generator, IMG_SIZE)
        
        model = Build_Model(model_name)
        model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(output_directory + "\\best_model.hdf5", verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
        early_stopping   = EarlyStopping(patience=STOPPING_PATIENCE, restore_best_weights=True)
        reduce_lr        = ReduceLROnPlateau('val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=LR_PATIENCE, min_lr=0.000003125)
        model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=INITIAL_LR), metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])         
                    
        history = model.fit_generator(
                    generator       = train_data_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = train_image_count // BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs          = epochs,
                    validation_data = val_data_generator,
                    validation_steps= val_image_count // BATCH_SIZE,
                    callbacks       = [model_checkpoint, early_stopping, reduce_lr],
                    shuffle         = False)
                                                       
           
        # Load the last best model
        model = load_model(
            output_directory + "\\best_model.hdf5")

        # Evaluate model on test set
        predictions = model.predict_generator(test_data_generator, test_image_count // BATCH_SIZE + 1)
        y_true = test_data_generator.classes
        y_pred = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
            
           
        print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=CLASSES, target_names=CLASS_NAMES))
        report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, labels=CLASSES, target_names=CLASS_NAMES, output_dict=True)
        with open(output_directory + '\\classification_report.csv', 'w') as f:
            for key in report.keys():
                f.write("%s,%s\n" % (key, report[key]))
        conf_arr = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=CLASSES)
        print(conf_arr)
        np.savetxt(output_directory + "\\confusion_matrix.csv", conf_arr, delimiter=",")

        # Clear model from GPU after each iteration
        print("Finished testing fold {}\n".format(k + 1))
        K.clear_session()
        k = k + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
   Tuning_Model()
```

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator'>, <class 'NoneType
```

Comment: please post a reproducible code snippet and also the stack trace of the error.

Comment: I add partially the code, I change the TensorFlow's version, may it is the problem

Comment: I code is not accessible, the Google drive says access denied....

Comment: I edit the message , sorry

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether training/testing data are in the form of numpy arrays before fitting the model?

Also it might be the case where you are importing model from keras like `keras.Sequential()` but the generator from Tensorflow like `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator()`.

Comment: Yes I checked , it is not the reason